# How to create subcategories in Magento using API SOAP?

Tags: api, magento, soap, categories

I am using Magento standard API SOAP to create categories and sub-categories.

Here is the code i am using to insert categories:

```
$client = new SoapClient('http://magentohost/api/soap/?wsdl');

$session = $client->login('apiUser', 'apiKey');
$result = $client->call($session, 'catalog_category.create', array(2, array(
'name' => 'Category name',
'is_active' => 1,
'position' => 1,

'available_sort_by' => 'position',
'custom_design' => null,
'custom_apply_to_products' => null,
'custom_design_from' => null,
'custom_design_to' => null,
'custom_layout_update' => null,
'default_sort_by' => 'position',
'description' => 'Category description',
'display_mode' => null,
'is_anchor' => 0,
'landing_page' => null,
'meta_description' => 'Category meta description',
'meta_keywords' => 'Category meta keywords',
'meta_title' => 'Category meta title',
'page_layout' => 'two_columns_left',
'url_key' => 'url-key',
'include_in_menu' => 1,
)));
```

Til here everything is ok, and success, But i am really confuse how to put subcategories under the categories i have created. I have tried using catalog_category.move but no result.

Any of you been through this trick? Thank you

Comment: you have to set path for sub cateogory like `'path' =>1/2/`.

Comment: Yes ok, that it a good idea but it does not let me create the paths without first declaring the entity_id which in this case magento create that not me, i have tried to insert the entity id like 'entity_id' => $some_value_comes_form_DB and it not allow me to do it if that is possible i could declare my path as 'path' => '1/2/$somevalue_from_DB/$other_value'. the problem is that i am creating these categories from another database call and they have their own Keys and id's which has to be declared. Any idea?

Comment: yes off course you can set your own entity id. i have recently worked on that situation and get success to create category with my own id.I just put my code as answer below.Please check it out it may give some idea to create category as per your requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$category->setStoreId(0); // 0 = default/all store view. If you want to save data for a specific store view, replace 0 by Mage::app()->getStore()->getId().

//if update
if ($id) {
  $category->load($id);
}

$general['name'] = "My Category";
$general['path'] = "1/3/"; // catalog path here you can add your own ID
$general['description'] = "Great My Category";
$general['meta_title'] = "My Category"; //Page title
$general['meta_keywords'] = "My , Category";
$general['meta_description'] = "Some description to be found by meta search robots. 2";
$general['landing_page'] = ""; //has to be created in advance, here comes id
$general['display_mode'] = "PRODUCTS"; //static block and the products are shown on the page
$general['is_active'] = 1;
$general['is_anchor'] = 0;
$general['page_layout'] = 'two_columns_left';

//$general['url_key'] = "cars";//url to be used for this category's page by magento.
//$general['image'] = "cars.jpg";


$category->addData($general);

try {
    $category->setId(255); // Here you cant set your own entity id
    $category->save();
    echo "Success! Id: ".$category->getId();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, i have a question where do you put this code under soap? Your answer make sense thank you very much

Comment: why you want to use soap api? its also possible using just script.

Comment: But that is only doing this inside magento, with soap i can do it directly from my local machine such as creating , updating, deleting. But also with SOAP i can create products, attributes,price rules ect.. Thats why i wanted to use Magento SOAP

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a 2 year old thread. But I am still posting my answer. It might help someone.

I am new to Magento and this is my first project. So, not sure if below code is really very efficient. I used SOAP catalog_category.create :

```
<?php
/**
 *                      ---NOTE---NOTE---NOTE---
 * Upload file must contain only those fields where the value is neither null nor blank.
 * Default values are already set for all the fields.
 * @var unknown
 */

$target_dir = "uploads/";
$filename = "category_tree_create_1443881125.csv";
$target_file = $target_dir . $filename;

//Web service sessoin initialization
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://localhost/magento-dhana/api/v2_soap/?wsdl'); // TODO : change url
$sessionId = $proxy->login('yourapiuser', 'apiuserpassword'); // TODO : change login and pwd if necessary

    $categoryIds = array();

    //prepare the initial attributes array required to upload
    $attrbutesFinal = array(

            'name' => '',
            'is_active' => 1,
            'position' => 1,
            'available_sort_by' => array('position'),
            'custom_design' => null,
            'custom_apply_to_products' => null,
            'custom_design_from' => null,
            'custom_design_to' => null,
            'custom_layout_update' => null,
            'default_sort_by' => 'position',
            'description' => '',
            'display_mode' => null,
            'is_anchor' => 0,
            'landing_page' => null,
            'meta_description' => ' ',
            'meta_keywords' => ' ',
            'meta_title' => ' ',
            'page_layout' => '',
            'url_key' => '',
            'include_in_menu' => 1,
    );


        $fileURL = $target_file;
        //$content = file_get_contents($fileURL, false);
        $content = file($fileURL);

        $rowCount = 0;
        foreach ($content as $row){

            $row = str_replace("\r\n", "", $row);
            $rowAsArray = explode(",", $row);

            if($rowCount === 0){
                //we collect the header row here and keep it separate
                $headerRow = $rowAsArray;
                $columns = count($headerRow);
            }else{

                for ($i = 0; $i < $columns; $i++) {
                    //an associative array is created with header row columns as keys and 
                    //columns of subsequent rows as values
                    //This is the format required by the web service as well
                    if ($headerRow[$i] === 'available_sort_by'){
                        //THIS COLUMN NEEDS AN ARRAY
                        $attrbutesFinal[$headerRow[$i]] = array($rowAsArray[$i]);
                    }else {

                        $attrbutesFinal[$headerRow[$i]] = $rowAsArray[$i];
                    }

                }
                //create category ---> SOAP call
                //if parent calumn has the ID (checked if it is number or not by calling intval() ) then
                //call soap directly using it as 'parent'
                if (intval($attrbutesFinal['parent']) > 1){

                    $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryCreate($sessionId, intval($attrbutesFinal['parent']), $attrbutesFinal);
                }else {

                    foreach ($categoryIds as $key => $val){

                        if ($attrbutesFinal['parent'] === $key){
                            $result = $proxy->catalogCategoryCreate($sessionId, intval($val), $attrbutesFinal);
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ($result > 0){

                    //File contains category name as parent but the web service needs the 
                    //ID.  while uploading new categories, we do not know the category ids yet
                    //So, once the category is created, we collect its ID here
                    $categoryIds[$attrbutesFinal['name']] = $result;
                }
            }

            //var_dump($rowAsArray);

            $rowCount += 1;
        }

        echo "<strong>Categories created ===> </strong></br>";
        var_dump($categoryIds);
?>
```

Here, once the parent category is created, I collect the entity ID created and use it to create its children.

I use the csv file with below data:

name    parent  description
HEALTH AND COSMETICS    63  HEALTH AND COSMETICS
HAIR CARE   HEALTH AND COSMETICS    HAIR CARE

IT assumes that I know entity ID of one category, root or some category below the root.
This works for me. But, I think this can be made more efficient.

Thank you
Dhananjay